# allocating memory for repository constructor c++

Tags: c++

How can I allocate memory for a repository in C++?

This is the repository class:

```
class Repository{

private:
    DynamicVector<Medicine> MedList;
};
```

When I was using structs in C the initRepository function (the constructor) was looking like this:

```
Repository* initRepository()
{
    Repository* repo =(Repository*)malloc(sizeof(Repository));
    repo->MedList=createVector();
    return repo;
}
```

but now I want to transform the C version into the C++ version. How do I do that?

Comment: C++ constructors that are automatically called are typeless functions that have the same name with the class. Put your init function into there.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to do anything special at all. Just create a `Repository` object:

```
Repository repo;
```

This will call the implicitly-defined defaulted (as in, default behaviour) default (as in, takes no arguments) constructor for `Repository`, which will also construct the member `MedList`. Once you've got your `Repository` object, you can do whatever you like with it.

If you want to initialize the member `MedList` with the result of the `createVector` function, you can define your own default constructor like so:

```
class Repository {
  public:
    Repository()
      : MedList(createVector())
    { }
  private:
    DynamicVector<Medicine> MedList;
};
```

This uses a member initialization list (everything after the `:`) to initialize `MedList`.